# Запятая в причастном обороте!

Tags: пунктуация

«Заместитель начальника отдела по раскрытию преступлений, совершаемых с использованием информационно-телекоммуникационных технологий УУР МВД по Республике Крым, подполковник полиции Вася Иванов». Где заканчивается причастный оборот «совершаемых...»? Склоняюсь, что запятая должна быть перед УУР...

Comment: Есть у меня товарищ Вася Иванов, правда, не подполковник.))

Comment: :)... Настоящую фамилию я раскрывать не стала..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: Заместитель начальника отдела по раскрытию преступлений, ***совершаемых с использованием информационно-телекоммуникационных технологий***, УУР МВД по Республике Крым, подполковник полиции Вася Иванов.

Расшифровка: Заместитель начальника отдела по раскрытию преступлений, совершаемых с использованием информационно-телекоммуникационных технологий, **Управления уголовного розыска Министерства внутренних дел по Республике Крым**.

Answer (score 0):

Заместитель начальника отдела Управления уголовного розыска Министерства внутренних дел по Республике Крым по раскрытию преступлений, совершаемых с использованием информационно-телекоммуникационных технологий.   Полагаю, неверно разрывать название должности причастным оборотом